# Organizing downloaded python libraries

Tags: python, macos

I've noticed that my python libraries and other dependencies are stored at various places around my directory hierarchy. For example,

- `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`
- `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`
- `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/`
- `/Users/<name>/bin/`

A recent failure to upgrade one of (and that my `$PATH` var now contains 7 directories) makes me believe that I need to somehow reorganize these files.

1) When 'pip'ing or 'brew'ing a new library, say, is there any particular directory the downloaded files should go to? (e.g. /Library/python/2.7/site-packages )

2) Are there any useful sources of how to organize one's own personal file system? (Specifically with downloaded python libraries, or more generally)

Comment: have you heard of virtualenv?

Comment: I think you're confusing things that are separate. `/usr/bin/python` is the actual executable, not a place where Python libraries are stored. `/usr/local/python` shouldn't exist at all; if you meant `/usr/local/bin/python`, then that's again an actual executable, and it also means you apparently installed an extra copy of Python even though you already had one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take these out of order:

> 1) When 'pip'ing or 'brew'ing a new library, say, is there any particular directory the downloaded files should go to?

First, the downloaded files go into a temporary directory and get deleted after installation. That's automatically taken care of by both `pip` and `brew`.

For Python packages, whether installed by `pip` or not, you do have a choice between system-wide and user-specific installs (see [User Installs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#user-installs)), but otherwise, they just go into your Python site-packages. That location can be configured, but there's no good reason to. For Apple's pre-installed Python, it's `/Library/python/2.7/site-packages`. If you want more control, you shouldn't try to keep custom site-packages directories around (or multiple Python installations); use [`virtualenv`](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/) to built separate virtual environments, and then `pip` will install into whichever environment is currently active, instead of installing into your normal site-packages.

For programs and libraries that you install with `brew`, they get built into "kegs", isolated directories under `/usr/local/Cellar`, and then anything useful gets linked from there into `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/lib`, etc. If you want to know more, the Homebrew docs explain it all in detail. This of course includes libraries that you install as dependencies for Python packages. For example, if you `brew install libxslt` so you can `pip install lxml`, `brew` has no idea *why* you're installing `libxslt`, it just builds it in a keg and links it into `/usr/local/lib` like anything else.

Either way, you should *not* try to organize things. Both `pip` and `brew` know where they install things, and if you screw with them after the fact, uninstall, update, etc. will probably break.

---

> and a recent failure to upgrade one of (and that my $PATH var now contains 7 directories) makes me believe that I need to somehow reorganize these files.

Your `$PATH` has nothing to do with where Python looks for libraries. That's where your shell looks for executable programs. What Python looks in is [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path), which is a completely different thing.

---

> I've noticed that my python libraries and other dependencies are stored at various places around my directory hierarchy

No, they're really not. Every Python library you install goes into the site-packages directory.

So, what about all that other stuff on `sys.path`? Well, there's the Python standard library (`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7` and/or `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7.zip`), and extra modules that Apple pre-installs (`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python`), and various subdirectories (and zipfiles and eggfiles) within those two locations, and of course the current working directory (`'.'` or `''`), and that should be it.

> (i.e. /usr/local/python, /Library/python/2.7/site-packages, or /usr/bin/python..)

`/usr/bin/python` is not a place where libraries are stored. It's not a directory at all; it's an executable. It's the program that gets run when you type `python` at the terminal, or run a script that starts with `#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

`/usr/local/python` shouldn't exist at all. It's not part of the standard path for Apple's pre-installed Python, the official Python.org installation, or a Homebrew installation. If you've created this and added it to your `sys.path`… well, don't do that if you don't want to do that.

If you meant `/usr/local/bin/python`, then (a) that's an executable, not a place for libraries, and (b) it means you've installed a second Python alongside the Apple pre-installed one, and if you can't keep them straight, you should probably get rid of it.